# Slicing an array

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have this type of array

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,2,2,2};
```

I need to determine if the sum of the first half elements equal the sum of the second half, for example it should print:

> True

This is because `1 + 2 + 3` is equal to `2 + 2 + 2`

Comment: OK good luck. Let us know when you've tried something and if it didn't work.

Comment: @da_funk your question is too general.  You need to be more specific about the problem you have encountered and the solutions you have tried.

Comment: What if the array contains an uneven number of elements?

Comment: `return array.Take(array.Length/2).Sum() == array.Skip(array.Length/2).Sum()`?  I'll leave it to you to figure out odd length arrays

Comment: Ok, but I can slice an array I've tried foreach (int i in a.Slice(0, 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);

Comment: @da_funk The best way to ask this question would be for you to show the code you've tried that's not working. What `Slice` method are you referring to? That is not a built-in method for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2 };
        int middle = array.Length /2;
        // take the middle and calculate the first half and then skip to the middle and compare it with the next half
        bool isEqual = array.Take(middle).Sum() == array.Skip(middle).Sum();

        MessageBox.Show(isEqual.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner solution which your teacher will be *impressed* by:

```
bool result = array.Take(array.Length / 2).Zip(array.Reverse(), (x,y) => x - y).Sum() == 0;
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to slice the array in two parts. I've tried Slice method but it wont work

Comment: @da_funk can you please show how you tried to slice array? (edit your question)

Comment: foreach (int i in array.Slice(0, 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

Comment: @da_funk please edit your question if you want to add details. Side note - there is no Slice method in array